# How to use CGAL Arrangement_2 zone?

Tags: cgal

Although there is some documentation related to the `zone` free function of Arrangement_2 module, it is not mentioned in any example files and the usage is not obvious.

Assuming that I have an arrangement of points and line segments based on `CGAL::Arr_linear_traits_2`, I want to print out all faces visited when walking along a given `Segment_2`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the "assign" function:

```
void segment_intersect(Arrangement_2 &arr, Segment_2 &c)
{
  std::vector<CGAL::Object> zone_elems;
  Arrangement_2::Face_handle face;
  CGAL::zone(arr, c, std::back_inserter(zone_elems));
  for ( int i = 0; i < (int)zone_elems.size(); ++i )
    {
      if ( assign(face, zone_elems[i]) )
         //print the face index...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage actually is quite obvious. To get all elements intersected, this code is enough:

```
void segment_intersect(Arrangement_2 &arr, Segment_2 &c)
{
  std::vector<CGAL::Object> zone_elems;
  CGAL::zone(arr, c, std::back_inserter(zone_elems));
}
```

I have yet to find out how to extract faces out of the vector.